# Mostrar columnas que no tengan empty o null en todos los resultados

Tags: mysql, delete

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos INMENSA, tiene miles de millones de registros separados en un par de tablas pero la verdad que esta MUY desorganizadas, hay datos repetidos por todos lados y en muchas tablas hay muchas columnas que no tienen ningún tipo de dato útil.

Como podría hacer para buscar que columnas dentro de una tabla, tengan un contenido empty o null en todos los registros, para poder borrarlas.

Ejemplo de mi tabla Clientes:

```
| ID | NOMBRE | DIRECCION | DATOEMPTY | DATONULL | NOBORRAR | TELEFONO |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | jose   | XXXX 123  |     ''    |   null   |   ''     | 11223344 |
| 2  | juan   | XXXX 123  |     ''    |   null   |   asdasd | 11223344 |
| 3  | pepe   | XXXX 123  |     ''    |   null   |   null   | 11223344 |
```

En este caso todos los resultados tienen DATOEMPTY como empty... y DATONULL como null... y quisiera encontrar las columnas que no contengan nada como este caso para poder eliminarlas...
pero sin que me aparezca por ejemplo NOBORRAR ya que alguna entrada tiene un resultado como ser asdasd.

cabe destacar que tengo documentada (y mal documentada) la estructura de la base de datos y debo rehacerla bien... el problema es que miraría manualmente pero al tener miles de millones de registros y tener mas de 50 columnas por tablas, me es imposible.

Espero se haya entendido, estoy con las neurnas quemadas!

Comment: Y un count de esas columnas no sirvio?

Comment: O sea que quieres encontrar las filas que en la columna DATOEMPTY y en la columna DATONULL no tengan datos vacíos ni nulos respectivamente?

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es si hay una columna que tiene datos empty o null.. en todos los registros... directamente eliminarlas, porque han sido tablas que crearon y no se han utilizado... por ejemplo tengo una tabla con 8 millones de registros... y en esta tabla hay 2 columnas llamadas prueba1 y otra testeo1... esas 2 columnas tienen 8 millones de registros en empty y null, no se porque las pasaron a producción pero no tienen absolutamente nada y no se usan tampoco... y quiero eliminar todas las columnas que no tengan información útil

Comment: Lo que necesitas, segun entiendo, es identificar las columnas que en **todas las filas** tenga un dato vacío o nulo?

Comment: Claro, para poder eliminar esas columnas que no sirven para nada

Comment: Creo que deberías evaluar las columnas una a una con algo similar a esto `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL OR myColumn <> ''` si te trae algún registro, significa que **no toda la columna esta vacía o nula**. Si no trae nada, puedes eliminarla, no se utiliza.

Comment: Sin embargo, aclaro por las dudas... presta atención al código de la app que carga esa tabla. Tal vez no se utiliza porque el usuario decide no cargar el dato, pero si en un futuro carga algún dato ahí o si la consulta de INSERT contiene ese campo, eliminarla te va a dar problemas.

Comment: Genial, me sirve! igualmente trabajare en una copia obviamente... el problema que tenía es que había miles de tablas que se borraron los contenidos porque se fueron migrando a otros lados pero han dejado las tablas y muchas otras de pruebas, un asco todo... pero a ciencia cierta de los 8M de resultados si hay 1 solo que tiene que tener un campo, lo tiene seguro y a ciencia cierta también que las que están 100% vacías ahora son las que no sirven

Comment: @Liyo Redacta tu solución con la finalidad que la acepten y la comunidad pueda saber que existe una respuesta a esta pregunta.

Comment: @lsanchezo hecho!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que deberías evaluar las columnas una a una con algo similar a esto:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL OR myColumn <> ''
```

Si esa consulta te trae algún registro, significa que no toda la columna esta vacía o nula. Si no trae nada, puedes asumir que esa columna no se utiliza activamente.

Sin embargo, aclaro por las dudas, presta atención al código de la app que carga esa tabla. Tal vez no se utiliza porque el usuario decide no cargar el dato, pero si la consulta de `INSERT` contiene ese campo (al igual que algún `SELECT`), eliminarla te va a dar problemas.